# How to take away vertical space for programmatically added menu?

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I add a [MenuStrip](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.windows.forms.menustrip.aspx) to my form and I would like to add other controls below it like usual Point(0, 0) is the top left corner of empty form space. After I add the menu to my form and add more controls they overlap each other. So I want to take away some height of the client rect for the menu and a button with `Location = (0,0)` must be *RIGHT* below the menu.

**How do I do that ?**

If I assign a MainMenu to Menu property of the form it does that automatically but I really want and need to use MenuStrip.

---

**Edit:** this doesn't work:

```
MenuStrip menu = new MenuStrip();
menu.Items.Add("File");
menu.AutoSize = false;
menu.Height = 50;
menu.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
MainMenuStrip = menu;
Controls.Add(menu);

Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "hello world";
b.SetBounds(0, 25, 128, 50);
Controls.Add(b);
```

While this works like I would like it to do with MenuStrip:

```
Menu = new MainMenu();
Menu.MenuItems.Add("File");

Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "hello world";
b.SetBounds(0, 0, 128, 50);
Controls.Add(b);
```

Comment: Did you try to use Dock? If you add them all with DockStyle.Top they will be stacked vertically (don't forget to rever the insertion order to to change their index).

Comment: ...by the way: the Form has a MainMenuStrip property too.

Comment: @Adriano Yes, but it doesn't help. If you see the example the button will be under the menu.

Comment: because you explicitly set its bounds to be under the menu! Try what will happen to: 1) do not use SetBounds. 2) use SetBounds with Y >= 50 (now you set to 25!). 3) do not use SetBounds and use DockStyle.Top for the button too (with or without autosize)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `SetBounds(0, 25, 128, 50)`, you are actually setting `b.Top` to `25` (the second parameter). In order to set the top bound relative to the `menu` control, use:

```
b.SetBounds(0, menu.Bottom, 128, 50);
```

**[UPDATE]**

Alternatively, you could use:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private int menuStripHeight = 50;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.ControlAdded += Form1_ControlAdded;

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuStrip menu = new MenuStrip();
        menu.Items.Add("File");
        menu.AutoSize = false;
        menu.Height = menuStripHeight; ;
        menu.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
        MainMenuStrip = menu;
        Controls.Add(menu);

        Button b = new Button();
        b.Text = "hello world";

        // note that the position used is 0,0
        b.SetBounds(0, 0, 128, 50);

        Controls.Add(b);
    }

    void Form1_ControlAdded(object sender, ControlEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Control.GetType().FullName != "System.Windows.Forms.MenuStrip")
            e.Control.Top += menuStripHeight;
    }
}
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

Or you could just use a `Panel`:

```
MenuStrip menu = new MenuStrip();
menu.Items.Add("File");
menu.AutoSize = false;
menu.Height = menuStripHeight; ;
menu.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
MainMenuStrip = menu;
Controls.Add(menu);

Panel p = new Panel();
p.SetBounds(0, menuStripHeight, this.Width, this.Height);
Controls.Add(p);

Button b = new Button();
b.Text = "hello world";
p.Controls.Add(b);
b.SetBounds(0, 0, 128, 50);
```

Comment: I know what I'm doing there. But I need for new controls to have y location set to 0 and be under the menu. And It must be MenuStrip. I hope there is a little trick for that.

Comment: The update is an interesting idea but it won't work when I set location of my controls after the add (and I definitely do that). Or do you have a fix for that, too ?

Comment: Do you need to add the controls directly to the form's control collection? Why don't you use a `Panel` below the menu strip and add all the controls to it? This way, you should get the desired usage.

Comment: @mini-me: "I know what I'm doing there." -- I'm doubting this. I think there is something you aren't telling us.

Comment: Update 2 is what I'll go with. @siride how do I not know that I'm setting b.top to 25 ? The only thing I didn't tell is that I have working applications where a menu must be build into.

Answer (score 1):

Use DockStyle.Top in both MenuStrip and Panel, but add them in the reverse order. Adding a control with Dock=Top puts this last control closest to the border, that is, on top of all the other controls. So without resorting to private constants and event handlers:

```
MenuStrip menu = new MenuStrip() {
  AutoSize = false,
  Dock = DockStyle.Top
};
menu.Items.Add("File");

Panel p = new Panel(){
   Dock = DockStyle.Top
};

Controls.Add(p);
Controls.Add(menu);
MainMenuStrip = menu;

Button b = new Button(){
  Text = "hello world"
};
p.Controls.Add(b);
b.SetBounds(0, 0, 128, 50);
```